# Wondering about open port found while using VPN service

Tags: vpn, vulnerability-scanners, network-scanners, ports, port-knocking

I have noticed during port scanning that my "anonymous" IP has an open port (`111`) while I am using VPN.

Does this make me vulnerable as user or is it the provider's failure? Should I change providers or do I have nothing to worry about (since, if the providers' network security is compromised, mine is in risk as well)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE:** All of this assumes you are talking about **[TCP](http://www.speedguide.net/port.php?port=111)** 111 (vs UDP).

If you are using a VPN service, you are sharing that Public IP with many customers and being NAT'd somewhere along the way. This Public IP is *generally* not directly routable to you as a user of the service, as such, there isn't much to worry about.

That being said, it's hard to know (without more info/probing) *exactly* what is running on that open port. In general, ports 1-1023 fall in the *[Well-Known Ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers)* range, though that's not to say that something else can't be running on this port, but it's likely an RPC (remote procedure call) service like SunRPC.

**TL; DR** You're probably fine, but if you're still worried about, contact the VPN vendor and ask them exactly what it is and what it's used for.

Answer (score 0):

The port might be consumed by `rpcbind`. What `rpcbind` does, is described  [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/234154/exactly-what-does-rpcbind-do)

An excerpt:

> When a client signs up for a given interface on a particular host,
>   usually with a clnt_create() call, the stub code asks rpcbind on that
>   host a question, something like "on what UDP or TCP port is protocol
>   number X listening?" rpcbind, unlike most other ONC services, listens
>   on TCP and UDP port 111, so given a host name or IP address, a program
>   can just ask rpcbind on that host or IP address. rpcbind responds with
>   the appropriate port number, if a server has registered with it on
>   that host. That registration is done by the server process when it
>   calls svc_create().

Comment: This will give you **your** TCP/UDP 111, the OP asked about the IP address he's *presenting as*.

Comment: fair. modified the answer to be more specific